# how to fix error TF909091: Guest users are not permitted to access this organization as per organization policy

Tags: azure-devops

Error 403 forbidden TF909091: Guest users are not permitted to access this organization as per organization policy. For more information, please contact your organization administrator.

tried to look into azure portal to find the way to change organization setting for Azure Devops Instance, without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

> how to fix error TF909091: Guest users are not permitted to access this organization as per organization policy

You can try to check if this organization is backed by AAD, and make sure this account has been added to AAD.

You can access to https://portal.azure.com to check the User list.

If you access the organization get this error, you may need to contact your organization administrator to check if the Security policies all been turned on in this organization and if your account in the Project Collection Administrators group.

Organization setting -> Policy:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know what can be done if the the organization administrator, which created the organization, is a guest user in the AAD himself?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after enabled external guest access under Devops Org settings-> policies->User policies